# How do I tell if mysql replication is occurring over SSL

Tags: encryption, mysql

We have a SQL server replication in place. I'm trying to ensure that the replication is occurring over secure channels. Given that `MASTER_SSL_Allowed` is true ("Yes"), does this suggest things are traveling over SSL/TLS?

How can I be sure that the replication connection is encrypted? How can I effectively *forbid* unencrypted traffic between master and replication?

`mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.10.100
                  Master_User: slave_user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000192
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 37748817
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000032
                Relay_Log_Pos: 1244
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000092
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: omega
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 37748817
              Relay_Log_Space: 124980
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
           Master_SSL_CA_File: /etc/mysql/certs/omega-ca-cert.pem
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: /etc/mysql/certs/omega-client-cert.pem
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: /etc/mysql/certs/omega-client-key.pem`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things you can do

## SUGGESTION #1 : Check the Master

Make sure MySQL was started on the Master with lines like these in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=cacert.pem
ssl-cert=server-cert.pem
ssl-key=server-key.pem
```

Login to the Master, and run

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
```

You should see something like this:

```
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| have_openssl  | DISABLED |
| have_ssl      | DISABLED |
| ssl_ca        | ...      |
| ssl_capath    | ...      |
| ssl_cert      | ...      |
| ssl_cipher    | ...      |
| ssl_key       | ...      |
+---------------+----------+
```

If [have_open_ssl](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_have_openssl) and [have_ssl](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_have_ssl) are disabled, then mysqld on the Master is not using SSL.

Please read the MySQL Documentation on [ssl_ca](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-options.html#option_general_ssl-ca), [ssl_capath](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-options.html#option_general_ssl-capath), [ssl_cert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-options.html#option_general_ssl-cert), [ssl_cipher](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-options.html#option_general_ssl-cipher) and [ssl_key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-options.html#option_general_ssl-key) on how to use them. Evidently, if none of them are set, even if [have_open_ssl](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_have_openssl) and [have_ssl](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_have_ssl) are enabled, then mysqld on the Master is not using SSL.

## SUGGESTION #2 : Check the MySQL Grants on the Master

The connection itself should be using SSL options. In the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` output, I see you have a user called `slave_user`. On the Master, please run this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),';')
INTO @slaveusergrants FROM mysql.user WHERE user='slave_user';
PREPARE s FROM @slaveusergrants; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

In the output of this, you should see one or more of the following:

```
REQUIRE SSL
REQUIRE SUBJECT
REQUIRE X509
REQUIRE ISSUER
REQUIRE CIPHER
```

If the slave user on the Master has at least one of these things defined in its grants, the CHANGE MASTER TO command you run on the Slave needs to match the SSL settings on the Master.

For more clarification, please read [Setting Up Replication Using SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-solutions-ssl.html) from MySQL Documentation

## SUGGESTION #3 : Check the Live Connection

You should use [tcpdump and inspect port 3306](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tcpdump-capture-record-protocols-port/). If you see stuff in plain text, SSL ain't working for you. If you don't, that does not mean it's encrypted either. Why ? [According to the Security Guidelines in the MySQL Documentation (see the bottom of the page)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/security-guidelines.html):

> Do not transmit plain (unencrypted) data over the Internet. This
> information is accessible to everyone who has the time and ability to
> intercept it and use it for their own purposes. Instead, use an
> encrypted protocol such as SSL or SSH. MySQL supports internal SSL
> connections. Another technique is to use SSH port-forwarding to create
> an encrypted (and compressed) tunnel for the communication.
>
> Learn to use the tcpdump and strings utilities. In most cases, you can
> check whether MySQL data streams are unencrypted by issuing a command
> like the following:
>
> shell> tcpdump -l -i eth0 -w - src or dst port 3306 | strings This
> works under Linux and should work with small modifications under other
> systems.
>
> Warning If you do not see cleartext data, this does not always mean
> that the information actually is encrypted. If you need high security,
> consult with a security expert.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of `tcpdump`, `Wireshark`, or other network packet analyzer. That's the best way I can think of to prove positive that the replication is happening over TLS instead of cleartext. The technique of "checking the master" here isn't helpful, because it only shows whether the master *can* support TLS, not if it's actually being used. Likewise, you may want to ensure that TLS is actually working before you modify the `GRANT`s for the user to require TLS.